# bug in recursively building mongodb selection

Tags: haskell

When I type this into GHCI:

```
merge [] [(pack "text") =: (pack "hey"), (pack "text") =: (pack "there")]
```

I see:

```
[ text: "hey", text: "there"]
```

Yet when I run this code:

```
tagsSelector :: Selector -> [String] -> Selector
tagsSelector selector tags = case tags of
    [] -> selector
    t:ts -> tagsSelector (merge selector [(fieldToText Tags) =: t]) ts
```

and this test case:

```
testTagsSelector = TestCase (do
    assertEqual "The tags selector for two tags should match..."
        [(fieldToText Tags) =: "city", (fieldToText Tags) =: "urban"]
            (tagsSelector [] ["city", "urban"]))
```

The test fails with:

```
The tags selector for two tags should match...
expected: [ tags: "city", tags: "urban"]
 but got: [ tags: "city"]
```

If I add more tags to the input of tagsSelection, the resulting selection is only a field with the last tag entered in the list. What's wrong with the recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
merge [pack "text" =: pack "hey"] [pack "text" =: pack "there"]
```

gives

```
[ text: "hey"]
```

so the solution is:

```
tagsSelector :: Selector -> [String] -> Selector
tagsSelector selector tags = case tags of
    [] -> selector
    t:ts -> tagsSelector (merge [] (selector ++ [(fieldToText Tags) =: t])) ts
```